# SQL Server, I can execute sqlcmd with trusted connection but not sqlpackage

Tags: sql-server, sqlcmd, sqlpackage

We have some deployment scripts that use a combination of dacpacs through sqlpackage and straight scripts using sqlcmd.

When I execute the sqlpackage `dac\sqlpackage.exe /p:BlockOnPossibleDataLoss=False /p:BackupDatabaseBeforeChanges=True /a:Publish /sf:.\somedeploy.dacpac /tcs:"Data Source=MyDB;Initial Catalog=MyCatalog;Trusted_Connection=True;"`

I get an error message `*** Could not deploy package. Unable to connect to target server.`  I have login auditing turned on in sql and the message I am getting is `Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication. [CLIENT: 111.222.223.224]`

However, I can run our sql scripts through sqlcmd no problem by using the -E argument.
`sqlcmd -i Permissions\CreateSqlUser.sql -S MyDB -E`

I am running from a commandline that is set to "Run As Administrator" and am currently signed in as the admin.  This is running on a Windows Server 2012 VM.  I am using sql 2014.  We have other installs that haven't had problems but this is our first 2014 install so we are trying to determine if something changed or if we are missing something and if so what.

If I run from profiler I don't see any audit log error messages.  I checked the filters and what events I'm listening for and they all look good.  Inside sql when I run `exec sys.sp_readerrorlog 0, 1, 'Login Failed'` I do get the messgaes to show up.  (I might be doign something wrong in profiler).  Also they show up in the system event logs.  I'm not seeing anyplace where it tells me anything about the user attempting to login though.

If don't use trusted connection for sqlpackage and instead use a username and password it works fine.  However, part of what our deployment script does is create the users so our preference would be to not do this.